# Moving Circle to Top of Border With CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Decomposing my larger problem into this simple statement, I have a blue circle inside a box with a red border.

How do I keep the circle in the center but make it overlap over the top, horizontal line of the box's border?

My attempt looks like to reach the final result: https://jsfiddle.net/pgcft3z7/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    Circle Text Here
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
  position:absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 200px;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: red;
}
```

This involves me needing to manually specify a `left` and `top` which seems like it won't remain centered or will be very responsive.

Example of what it currently looks like:

https://jsfiddle.net/pgcft3z7/

Comment: So you want it to extend beyond the bounds of the red box? That is what I am understanding that you mean. Or do you just want it to touch the line?

Comment: Use relative positioning to keep the circle centered, and move it up with the relative positiong: https://jsfiddle.net/pgcft3z7/5/

Answer (score 3):

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/pgcft3z7/4).

```css
.circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.border {
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}
.container {
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="border">

  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    Circle Text Here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.line{
  position:relative;        /* in order to contain inner absolute circle pos */
  margin-top:50px;
  background:red;
  height:0;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.circle{
  position: absolute;
  width:40px; height:40px;
  top:50%;    left:50%;                /* 50% of parent */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    /* -50% of self */
  
  background:blue;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add these to your circle class:

```
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this one https://jsfiddle.net/pgcft3z7/7/

```css
.circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
  position:relative;
  top: -65px;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    Circle Text Here
  </div>
</div>
```